# How to install setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to install setuptools. When I run "sh setuptools-0.6c9-py2.4.egg" I get the following message:

> Permission denied:
>   '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/test-easy-install-26338.write-test'

It is expectable, since I do not have root permissions on the system. Some how I came to the idea of creating a "Virtual" Python.

I download "virtual-python.py" and run it using the site-wide Python. It creates "lib", "bin" and "include" sub-directories in my home-directory. In the end of the output of "virtual-python.py" I see the following message:

> You're now ready to download
>   ez_setup.py, and run
>   /home/myname/bin/python ez_setup.py

I download this file and run it. But than I get the same error message:

> Permission denied:
>   '/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/test-easy-install-925.write-test'

OK. I use "prefix" to force ez_setup.py to write to the local directory:

```
/home/myname/bin/python ez_setup.py --prefix=~
```

And then I get:

> - You can set up the installation directory to support ".pth" files by
>     using one of the approaches described
>     here:
>
> http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html#custom-installation-locations

So, I am redirected to the same page which I read before. So, I do not know what to do now.

I also have another hint:

> - You can add the installation directory to the PYTHONPATH
>     environment   variable.  (It must then
>     also be on PYTHONPATH whenever you run
>     Python and want to use the package(s)
>     you are installing.)

But if I type:

```
PYTHONPATH=/home/myname/lib/python2.4/site-packages
```

I still get the same result as if Python does not see my environment variables.

Can anybody, pleas, help me with that?

Answer (score 9):

Just adding extra detail to what already have been said.

1. Download `tar.gz` of the latest version of [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
2. Unpack it.
3. You don't even need to install it, just run `virtualenv.py`, for example:
    `virtualenv-1.3.3/virtualenv.py mypyenv`
    `mypyenv` virtual Python environment will be created in your current directory and it will contain `easy_install` ready to use.
4. Activate it:
   `source mypyenv/bin/activate`
   or on Windows do:
    `mypyenv\Scripts\activate.bat`
    Now, your PATH is set to point at Python executables under `mypyenv`. From this shell session, you will be able to `easy_install` whatever you want, and resulting stuff will be installed in the guts of `mypyenv` instead of your default Python location, thus obviating any need for admin privileges.

*OS X Snow Leopard caveat:*
For some reason, `virtualenv-1.3.3` does not play well with built-in Python under `/System/Frameworks`. I had to build a separate version of Python from source, and installed it under `/usr/local/python_2_6_2`.
With that done, I used `--python /usr/local/python_2_6_2/bin/python` option with virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv comes with setuptools pre-installed, I believe. I know that it at least comes with `easy_install`. You should then be able to run:

```
/home/myname/bin/easy_install setuptools
```

This should install the newest version of setuptools on your virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You have to activate your virtualenv first, else you just have a bunch of folders. Use the full path to the scripts in your virtual env's `bin` or do `source bin/activate`

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can run next command

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python`

Comment: No root access.