# Python ImportError on web hosting

Tags: python, extract, importerror

I'm fairly new to Python, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

I have been using the [Topia TermExtract](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/topia.termextract/) package, and the code I wrote has been working fine on my local machine (Mac OS 10.6.5; Python 2.6). However, when I copy the entire directory, complete with package files, to my GoDaddy hosting, I get this error:

```
    File "test.py", line 2, in ?
    from topia.termextract import extract
  File "/home/DIRECTORY_HERE/topia/__init__.py", line 1, in ?
    import pkg_resources
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work. Here is the script I wrote:

```
import sys
from topia.termextract import extract
extractor = extract.TermExtractor()
extractor

extractor.filter = extract.DefaultFilter(singleStrengthMinOccur=1)
# join array into string from command-line arguments.
str = ' '.join(sys.argv)
x = extractor(str)
print "\nExtracted text:\n"
# for each extracted word, print it out.
for i in range(0, len(x)):
   if ((x[i][0])[-3:] != ".py"):
      print x[i][0]

print "\n"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `pkg_resources` package is part of setuptools. Install that on the hosting.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know if I am able to install that on GoDaddy's shared hosting? Or will I need a dedicated server?

Comment: It doesn't have any C modules, so you should have no problem installing it in a private directory.

Comment: It's saying I don't have permissions to write to /usr/lib/python2.4, and the installation fails.

Comment: @Rodney just upload it into a directory in your shared path, and include it like any other package that you've written

Answer (score 1):

I got it. I had to install VirtualEnv. If anyone has a similar problem, check out this post:

[How to install setuptools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449396/how-to-install-setuptools/1452826#1452826)