# Installing a python package/tool by a non root user

Tags: python, setuptools

(1) I have to install one python package (HTSeq) but i dont have root privileges.

The package need python 2.4 or latest version. We have python 2.3 on our cluster.

Thus I installed python 2.7 on my one local directory 
using

```
./configure --prefix=/home/amit/tools/localpython 
make 
make install
```

(2) The package also requires numpy : so I also installed it on my local directory using:

```
/home/amit/tools/localpython/bin/python2.7 setup.py install --home=/home/amit/tools/localnumpy
```

and done

```
>>> sys.path.append("/home/amit/tools/localnumpy/lib/")
```

(3) I downloaded the tar file of HTSeq (Which i want to download) and run

```
/home/amit/tools/localpython/bin/python2.7 setup.py install --home=/home/amit/tools/localhtseq
```

it is throwing following error:

```
Could not import 'setuptools',
falling back to 'distutils'.
Setup script for HTSeq: Failed to import 'numpy'.
Please install numpy and then try again to install HTSeq.
```

Kindly provide me some hint on how to get over it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setuptools is another requirement which you need to install that package.

One option is to use virtualenv to create a contained python environment. This can be made everywhere and is owned by the user who creates it.

To install virtualenv without admin rights (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452826/708221)):

Download tar.gz of the latest version of virtualenv.
Unpack it.
You don't even need to install it, just run virtualenv.py, for example:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.7.1.2.tar.gz
tar -xzf virtualenv-1.7.1.2.tar.gz
/home/amit/tools/localpython/bin/python2.7 virtualenv-1.7.1.2/virtualenv.py env

env/bin/pip install HTSeq
env/bin/pip install numpy
```

Now run your script using the python binary in the virtual environment:

```
env/bin/python myscript.py
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper Van den Bosch, I will try it (after little googling) using virtualenv as i am unaware of this, if i encounter any prob i will let you know

Comment: alright, I have added some commands, let me know how it works out!

Comment: Dear Jasper, its working...i installed both packages and now imported HTseq in current python 2.7 session on terminal. thanks

Comment: If you're going to be using virtualenv (which is definitely recommended) you should look into [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/), it makes using lots of virtualenvs simple.

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to install [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) (it is necessary to run setup.py of your HTSeq).

Download sources *tar.gz* `setuptools-0.6c11.tar.gz`, unpack it, and then do the steps like you installed python2.7, but in the folder where you unpacked setuptools sources:

```
./configure --prefix=/home/amit/tools/localpython 
make 
make install
```

2) When you will install setuptools, a `easy_install` executable will apear in `python2.7/scripts/` folder. You can use it to install packages easily:

```
/home/amit/tools/localpython/bin/python2.7/scripts/easy_install HTSeq
```

it will automatically find the package and will download and install it for you along with all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks SergeanT, but sorry to bother you once again - when i type python on terminal, it automatically takes old python version (2.3). I have to use python 2.7. so when i run sh sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg it gives an error : setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg: line 3: exec: python2.7: not found

Comment: It is better to install setuptools from sources (use `tar.gz` link), then do everything like you installed python2.7 (`./configure --prefix=...`, `make`, `make install`. I have updated my answer with these steps.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to install `pip` as the local user and then install packages. As [explained in the pip docs (check for OS specifics)](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) you can install it as follows - obtain the `get-pip.py` script, then run it:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Once it is installed you can then install packages like this:

```
python -m pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```