# install django-crispy-forms in virtual environment

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I'm working on web application project and i would lik to use django-crispy-forms as style for my login etc..
i have created clean virtual environment for my project and installed what i need for the project until now ..!

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$ python --version

Python 3.4.0

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$ pip list

Django (1.8.4)

django-registration-redux (1.2)

pip (7.1.2)

psycopg2 (2.6.1)

setuptools (18.2)

wheel (0.24.0)

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$ pip freeze

Django==1.8.4

django-registration-redux==1.2

psycopg2==2.6.1

wheel==0.24.0

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$

now i would like to install django-crispy-forms but pip can not help me .!

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$ pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms

Collecting django-crispy-forms

Using cached django-crispy-forms-1.5.2.tar.gz

setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution

(env)amr@T510:~/viteco$

Answer (score 0):

> setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution

Looks like you need `setuptools`.

Try this question for [how to install setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449396/how-to-install-setuptools?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks Carlton .
There was a conflict with my virtual environment but i fixed it by reinstall virtual environment .